# TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, applicationinsights-react-js

I have a static class that has some static functions that wrap around some Application Insights functions in a react-typescript project.

Upon the application loading one of the static functions is called which in turn calls another static function. Before that second static function is even entered the application throws an error
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator`

```js
// wrapper function 
public static TrackAndReturnException(
  errorMessage: string | Error,
  caller: string,
  severityLevel = SeverityLevel.Error,
  properties ? : any
): Error {
  // Error thrown here and TrackTrace is never entered
  this.TrackTrace(
    errorMessage.toString(),
    caller,
    severityLevel,
    ...properties
  )
}

// wrapper function
public static TrackTrace(
  message: string,
  caller: string,
  severityLevel = SeverityLevel.Verbose,
  properties ? : any
): void {

  // native function
  this.AppInsights.trackTrace({
    message: message,
    severityLevel: severityLevel,
    properties: {
      caller: caller,
      ...properties
    },
  })
}
```

However if use the native function (rather than the wrapper) the error goes away.

```js
// wrapper function 
public static TrackAndReturnException(
  errorMessage: string | Error,
  caller: string,
  severityLevel = SeverityLevel.Error,
  properties ? : any
): Error {
  // No error; TrackTrace (below) is not used
  this.AppInsights.trackTrace({
    message: errorMessage.toString(),
    severityLevel: severityLevel,
    properties: {
      caller: caller,
      ...properties
    },
  })
}

// wrapper function
public static TrackTrace(
  message: string,
  caller: string,
  severityLevel = SeverityLevel.Verbose,
  properties ? : any
): void {

  // native function
  this.AppInsights.trackTrace({
    message: message,
    severityLevel: severityLevel,
    properties: {
      caller: caller,
      ...properties
    },
  })
}
```

TrackAndReturnException is not called by an asynchronous `ComponentDidMount` function but is not within the returned promise itself.
I don't understand the connection here as to why that error would be thrown where it is. The work around is easy enough, but redundant. Has anyone seen this before and/or know why I'm experiencing this error where I am?

Comment: Sounds like `properties` isn't iterable

Comment: Yes! Placing `...properties` in an object fixed the problem: `{...properties}`